# Integration by parts for contour integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, contour-integration

I came across the following step which I don't understand

> $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}e^{v\left(\frac{1}{3}t^3-\eta t\right)}(t^2-\eta)g(t)\mathrm{d}t=-\frac{1}{2\pi i v}\int_{C}e^{v\left(\frac{1}{3}t^3-\eta t\right)}g'(t)\mathrm{d}t$$

And I know that the integral contains the Airy-function
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}e^{v\left(\frac{1}{3}t^3-\eta t\right)}\mathrm{d}t=v^{-1/3}\operatorname{Ai}(\eta\ v^{2/3})$$
I tried integration by parts
\begin{align}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}e^{v\left(\frac{1}{3}t^3-\eta t\right)}(t^2-\eta)g(t)\mathrm{d}t
&=v^{-1/3}\operatorname{Ai}(\eta\ v^{2/3})\left[(t^2-\eta)g(t)\right]_C-v^{-1/3}\operatorname{Ai}(\eta\ v^{2/3})\int_{C}2t\ g(t)\mathrm{d}t\\
&-v^{-1/3}\operatorname{Ai}(\eta\ v^{2/3})\int_{C}(t^2-\eta)g'(t)\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}
Another integration by parts on the last two integrals (let $G(t):=\int g(t) \mathrm{d}t$)
\begin{align}
-v^{-1/3}\operatorname{Ai}(\eta\ v^{2/3})\int_{C}2t\ g(t)\mathrm{d}t&=-v^{-1/3}\operatorname{Ai}(\eta\ v^{2/3})[2t\ G(t)]_C+v^{-1/3}\operatorname{Ai}(\eta\ v^{2/3})2\int_{C}\ G(t)\mathrm{d}t\\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
-v^{-1/3}\operatorname{Ai}(\eta\ v^{2/3})\int_{C}(t^2-\eta)g'(t)\mathrm{d}t
&=
-v^{-1/3}\operatorname{Ai}(\eta\ v^{2/3})[(t^2-\eta)g(t)]_C+v^{-1/3}\operatorname{Ai}(\eta\ v^{2/3})\int_{C}2t\ g(t)\mathrm{d}t
\\
\end{align}
Then we are left with
\begin{align}
-v^{-1/3}\operatorname{Ai}(\eta\ v^{2/3})[2t\ G(t)]+v^{-1/3}\operatorname{Ai}(\eta\ v^{2/3})2\int_{C}\ G(t)\mathrm{d}t+
v^{-1/3}\operatorname{Ai}(\eta\ v^{2/3})\int_{C}2t\ g(t)\mathrm{d}t
\\
\end{align}
If I make another integration by parts I end up with $0$, so clearly there is something wrong. Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us integrate the derivative of function
$$ f(t)= e^{v\left(\frac{1}{3}t^3-\eta t\right)} g(t)
$$
over a contour $C$ such that
$$\int_C  f'(t) \,dt =0\,.$$
Such a contour can be a closed contour or a contour that goes to infinity in the directions in which $e^{v\left(\frac{1}{3}t^3-\eta t\right)}$ vanishes.

In this case from the product rule, we have that
$$\int_C e^{v\left(\frac{1}{3}t^3-\eta t\right)} v (t^2-\eta) g(t) \,dt + \int_C e^{v\left(\frac{1}{3}t^3-\eta t\right)}g'(t)\,dt =0 $$
which is your result in a different form.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much.

I have one question though, can I a priori know that this contour exists (for any $g(t)$) that $\int_C f'(t) \mathrm{d}t=0$ or do I have to check whether there are some singularities? Thank you

Comment: @Matriz: Of course, you have to check for singularities. In your application (having the typical contour for an Airy function), you should assume that $g(t)$ is a holomorphic function  which does not grow too much such that together with the exponential factor it still vanishes at infinity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!